# Remove last character in a cell using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a value in a cell as below

`( Abc','def','hij', 'klm' ,)`

I need to pass these values into a SQL query as parameters. In order to do so I need add an additional ' at the start so it reads as 'Abc' and remove the last , after m .

I have tried
`Right(C2,LEN(C2)-(LEN(C2)-1)))`

But above is deleting all my ,
I need only last , to be deleted

Comment: Do you have space after first bracket `(`? and does it need to eliminate?

Comment: Something like `=SUBSTITUTE(REPLACE(A1,2,1,"'")," ,)",")")`

Comment: @JvdV This shorter and easier.

Comment: No spac after first bracket

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below formula

```
=REPLACE(REPLACE(A1,1,2,"('"),LEN(REPLACE(A1,1,2,"('"))-2,2,"")
```

[image]

> Edit: VBA Codes. If there is no space after first bracket then try below codes.

```
Sub sSQL()
Dim x As String, z As String

    x = Range("A1")
    z = "('" & Mid(x, 2, Len(x) - 3) & ")"
    MsgBox z

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks.. the formula works fine. How can I conver the formula to a VBA code? I'm getting type mismatch error when I write rhe formula in my code

Comment: @user1838000 Check edited answer for VBA.